# Streaming Large (7 GB) S3 gz file in Rails 3.x to the Browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

I'm trying to stream a large Amazon S3 file to the browser using the Rails `send_data` method, however because the file is so large, the server runs out of memory and cannot complete the request.

The code looks something like this:

```
def download
  s3_obj.read
end

def download_file
  send_data(file.download, :filename => filename, :type => 'application/gzip', :disposition => 'attachment')
end
```

Is there a way to stream the chunks of the file with `send_data` so that it's a single file in the browser? the way I understand it is that `send_data` has to load the entire file into memory, then send all of that at once.

Comment: Fineuploader is a good JS library to upload files to S3 by chunks. though it is not easy to setup. If you need to add one to your application then it's ok, but maybe not worth it if your upload is only to happen once..

Answer (score 1):

You should use `send_file` instead of `send_data` as it allow you to set the buffer and more option.

[More information here](https://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.8/ActionController/Streaming/send_file).

**UPDATE**

If you want to download from S3, you can do this:

```
def download
  data = open("S3_OBJECT_URL") 
  send_file data.read, filename: filename, type: "application/gzip", disposition: 'attachment', stream: 'true', buffer_size: '4096' 
end
```

or

```
redirect_to s3_object.file.url
```

Comment: Does this allow you to send a file straight from S3 without Downloading it?

Comment: jeremie, I like this answer, however the `data = ...` still has to load the file into memory first. I like the redirect idea (things would be much simpler), but because of technical reasons, I cannot use a 302.